# i want to add hours in midnight value to display the destination time based on my timezone

Tags: java

I have just started learning java and was working through the test project. I need to get the destination time as per the destination timezone based on the time in my timezone.
For that, I am taking an input of time difference in the timezones. but not able to add it to the time.

Please help me in understanding this. my code is

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

   public class tripPlanner{

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    //Time Difference       
    timeDiff(new Scanner (System.in));
```

}

```
    // Time Difference Method
public static void timeDiff(Scanner input) {
System.out.print("whats is the time difference, in hours, between your home and your destination? ");
int addhours = input.nextInt();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String midnight = "24:00";
String noon = "12:00";
Date midnightValue = formatter.parse(midnight);
Date noonValue = formatter.parse(noon);
Date timeDiffnight = midnightValue.plusHours(addhours);
// Date timeDiffnight = midnightValue + diff1;
Date timeDiffnoon = noonValue + diff1;
System.out.print("That means that when it is midnight at home, it will be " + timeDiffnight + " at your destination");
System.out.print("and when it is noon at home it will be " + timeDiffnoon);
System.out.println("**********************");
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use java 8 java.time.* APIs. You can check below example and implement in your code. Let me know if you have any questions:

`import java.time.LocalTime;`

```
 int addHours = 2;
 LocalTime localTimeNoon = LocalTime.NOON;
 LocalTime localTimeMidnight = LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
       
 LocalTime adjustedTimeNoon = localTimeNoon.plusHours(addHours);
 LocalTime adjustedTimeMidnight = localTimeMidnight.plusHours(addHours);
       
 System.out.println(adjustedTimeNoon);
 System.out.println(adjustedTimeMidnight);
```

prints

```
14:00
02:00
```

If you need to another formatting, explore `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` API.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i tried it but it is showing error. " can not find symbol"

Comment: What is the complete error message? Be sure install java 8 on your machine of course